# Simple group representation $\iff$ surjection onto $M_n(k)$?

Tags: representation-theory

Given a finite group $G$ and a $kG$-module $S$, we get a representation $\rho: G \to \textrm{GL}(S)$ which extends linearly to $\rho: kG \to \textrm{End}_k(S)\cong M_n(k)$ for some $n$. Certainly, if $\rho$ is surjective onto $M_n(k)$, then $S$ is simple.

Is the converse also true? Given that $S$ is simple, do we know that $\rho: kG \to M_n(k)$ is surjective?

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether $\rho$ is _surjective_? It depends on the field $k$. If the field is algebraically closed and $\rho$ is an irreducible representation, then $\rho$ is a surjective map. On the other hand this does not need to be true if $k$ is not algebraically closed, take for example $k = \mathbb{R}$, $G$ the cyclic group of order $4$, and the $2$-dimensional representation where a generator of $G$ acts as a rotation by a quarter-turn. The image of this representation is a subalgebra of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ isomorphic to the complex numbers, in particular it only has dimension 2.

Comment: Thanks @Joppy, I also realised that the original thing is covered as an exercise in Webb's book, chapter 6, exercise 12.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobson_density_theorem for a big generalisation